# Как можно вычислить часовой пояс зная координаты населенного пункта ?

Tags: php

Есть координаты:

```
Address:Ufa, Republic of Bashkortostan, Russia
Latitude:54.8098660
Longitude:56.0939110
```

Как можно вычислить часовой пояс? Есть ли формула?

//спец. сервисы вычисления не нужны.

Comment: Границы часовых поясов проходят по водоразделам, границам областей и краев и еще черт-знает как - как вы представляете себе формулу? Push The Tempo %)

Comment: особенно интересна часть формулы, где будет учтено законодательство)) например то, что в России отменили переход на зимнее время ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude

Comment: @thunder: можно, вам нужно подлинковать `-ltelepathy`.

Comment: @VladD прогуливал в школе этот предмет, думал не пригодится... напрасно... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В распределении зон никакой логики нет, соответственно нет и формулы.
Используйте базу данных часовых поясов: http://www.iana.org/time-zones

Поскольку изменения время от времени происходят (например, летнее время могут вводить и отменять), вам придётся регулярно обновлять базу.

---

PS: вот пример кода, работающего с таблицей: http://edoceo.com/exemplar/php-timezone.

---

PPS: Для отображения координат в название страны, советуют базу данных: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Comment: беру на заметку

Comment: Я пробывал с этими базами а именно с tzdata2012 http://hashcode.ru/questions/192604/php-поиск-в-массиве-наиболее-приближенного-значения не получилось...что то я не догоняю(((

Answer (score 5):

Гугл знает все, просто правильно задавайте ему вопросы: http://ws.geonames.org/timezone?lat=54.8098660&lng=56.0939110

Comment: полезная штука, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

http://askgeo.com/ - готовые библиотеки под Java и .NET