# API текущего времени в каком то городе

Tags: php, javascript, api, время

Какие есть сервисы, для получения текущего времени по координатам, средствами пхп, жс?...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/192631/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Можно думаю на гитхабе поискать библиотеку

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно импользовать - [Google Maps Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start).
И тогда можно получить время используя ссылку такого формата.
Где "YOUR_API_KEY" это твой ключь от API.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=38.908133,-77.047119&timestamp=1458000000&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: Не понимаю как время из этого выбить.
Написано: Местное время в определенном местоположении представляет собой сумму параметра timestamp и значений в полях dstOffset и rawOffset из результата.

Но если я указываю координаты Москвы,  и текущий timestamp - а потом суммирую - получается на 4 часа больше.